# Converting old App to iPhone5. Tabbar floats above the bottom of the screen. Screen has resized to iPhone5

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios6

I'm working on a very old project that was done with the bare minimum of NIBS.
I've added the new Default images so that the screen now loads to iPhone5 size as confirmed when I see the image on the iPhone5 Simulator.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
    [self.window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults)
    {
        if ([[standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"user"] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"(null)"] == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            //NSLog(@"Setting user to default_user");
            [standardUserDefaults setObject:@"default_user" forKey:@"user"];
            [standardUserDefaults setObject:@"default_user" forKey:@"password"];
            [standardUserDefaults setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"logged_in_status"];
            [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
        }
    }

    UINavigationController *localNavigationController;

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

    SettingsVC *firstViewController;
    firstViewController = [[SettingsVC alloc] init];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
    [localNavigationController.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Settings" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_new_request.png"] tag:1];
    firstViewController.navigationItem.title=@"Settings";
    [localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
    [localNavigationController release];
    [firstViewController release];

    VideoMenuVC *secondViewController;
    secondViewController = [[VideoMenuVC alloc] init];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
    [localNavigationController.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Video" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_existing.png"] tag:2];
    secondViewController.navigationItem.title=@"Video";
    [localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
    [localNavigationController release];
    [secondViewController release];

    LoginVC *thirdViewController;
    thirdViewController = [[LoginVC alloc] init];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:thirdViewController];
    [localNavigationController.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Log On/Off" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_phone.png"] tag:3];
    thirdViewController.navigationItem.title=@"Log On/Off";
    [localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
    [localNavigationController release];
    [thirdViewController release];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

    [localControllersArray release];

    self.user_name = [[NSString alloc ]init];
    self.user_name = @"defaultFolder";

    NSLog(@"Frame Height: %f",self.window.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"Tab Height: %f",self.tabBarController.view.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"Tab Origin Y: %f",self.tabBarController.view.frame.origin.y);

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

When the Launch image appears it takes up the full area of the iPhone 5 Simulator screen.

When the app loads in fully and VideoMenuVC is displayed you can see that it is not using the full area. The white area under the tabbar should not be there.

Though looking at the NSLogs of the views height they seem correct.

[image: Image of screen and NSLogs]

I've been looking at this for a couple of hours and maybe I cant see the obvious because I'm looking too hard. I'd appreciate some fresh eyes/ideas as to what I've done wrong.

Many Thanks,
Code

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing found in your code which can cause this. I will recommend to check the size of the icon-images. In one of my project, I have used images of 60 * 60 or 70 * 60 pixels.

Comment: You mean the app icon images used by the user to start the app?

Comment: No, I talked about tabbar icons for example icn_new_request.png